# MongoDB Atlas trigger does not set field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have the following trigger function that is not function. I would like to know why it does not set the field createdAt:

```
const collection = context.services.get("comand-dev").db("test").collection("ownerDetails");
  const docId = changeEvent.documentKey._id;
  collection;
  collection.updateOne(
    {_id : docId} ,
    { 
      $set : 
        {
        createdAt: Date()
        } 
    }
  );
```

The trigger logs says OK but the field is not there

Comment: Does the collection have a document with _id of docId ?

Comment: I think so, how can I debug? The trigger is created on each _insert_ so maybe the _id is not created yet at this point? Is the trigger run before or after the actual insert?

Comment: What is `changeEvent` and where does it come from?

Comment: changeEvent comes from the trigger itself. please take a look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/change-events/#insert-event . It seems that _id exists so this is not the problem with my trigger

Comment: 1) What's the trigger type ? 2) Check whether the trigger is enabled 3) What operation types do the triggers apply for ? 4) Check whether it's for the correct service name i.e. 'command-dev' 5) Check whether it's for the correct database/collection.

Comment: Database trigger, is enabled, is applied only for inserts, service name is correct, database is correct, the trigger is trigged but it does not set the column value. Do you think printscreens can help?

Comment: Try `console.log(docId);`. Also I noticed in your snippet code, you have `collection;` on a line on its own (before updateOne), you should remove that.

Comment: I added console.log, it displays the correct identifier. I deleted the collection row, thanks for that. The problem needs to be somewhere in the update function

Comment: Could you update the question with the following information: 1) the document that you inserted 2) the `_id` value 3) the output of the `console.log(docId)` from the trigger 4) using `mongo` shell connect to the cluster and perform `find()` based on the newly inserted `_id` , could you find the document ?

Comment: yes, all the values are correct and the query returns the document

Comment: @TudorGrigoriu, would you mind posting the answer to question 1, 2, 3 ?

Comment: maybe        ` createdAt: new Date()`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. A small issue with the syntax. you have to add the quotes.

```
collection.updateOne(
{"_id" : docId} ,
    { 
      "$set" : 
        {
        "createdat": Date()
        } 
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out so I would share my solution. In my case, I convert _id object id to date and insert it as a new field for newly inserted document. The trigger will be configurated as insert trigger operation. Enable event ordering.

```
 exports = function (changeEvent) {
 const docId = changeEvent.documentKey._id;
 console.log(docId);
 const collection = 
 context.services.get("Cluster0").db("Driver").collection("Trip");
 collection.updateOne({_id: docId },
 [{
    "$addFields" : {
        "CreationDate" : {
            "$toDate" : "$_id"
        }
    }
}],{upsert: false}
);
};
```